# TypeError: QTableView(parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to show all may data in the database in my QTableView but the error

```
TypeError: QTableView(parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

always shows up in the end. I don't understand because all my data types in my database are varchars not int.

Here's the function where I call the data:

```
def connectDB(self):

        # TABLE
        columns = ['Time In','Time Out', 'Class', 'Color', 'Specific Attribute', 'Camera Number']
        tableWidget = QTableView(22, 6, self)
        tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(columns)
        tableWidget.setGeometry( 400, 50, 850, 692)
        tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()


        # CONNECTION
        conn = mariadb.connect(
        user="root",
        password="",
        host="localhost",
        port=3306,
        database="IRIS")

        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM iris_table")

        allSQLRows= cur.fetchall()
        tableWidget.setRowCount(len(allSQLRows))

        data = [allSQLRows]
        tableWidget.setModel(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following errors.

- QTableView does not accept the number of rows or columns in the constructor, so it seems that you have copied code for QTableWidget that does accept it.
- A model in Qt is not a array, list, etc. but a class that inherits from QAbstractItemModel.
- If you use QTableWidget then you cannot use a model since it already has one by default that cannot be modified.

Considering the above there are 2 possible solutions:

- Use QTableView with a model.

  ```py
  labels = [
      "Time In",
      "Time Out",
      "Class",
      "Color",
      "Specific Attribute",
      "Camera Number",
  ]
  view = QTableView(self)
  model = QStandardItemModel(0, 6)
  view.setModel(model)
  model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)
  view.setGeometry(400, 50, 850, 692)
  view.resizeRowsToContents()

  conn = mariadb.connect(
      user="root", password="", host="localhost", port=3306, database="IRIS"
  )

  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute("SELECT * FROM iris_table")

  allSQLRows = cur.fetchall()
  model.setRowCount(len(allSQLRows))

  for i, row_data in enumerate(allSQLRows):
      for j, data in enumerate(row_data):
          item = QStandardItem()
          item.setData(data, Qt.DisplayRole)
          model.setItem(i, j, item)
  ```
- Use QTableWidget

  ```py
  labels = [
      "Time In",
      "Time Out",
      "Class",
      "Color",
      "Specific Attribute",
      "Camera Number",
  ]
  view = QTableWidget(0, 6, self)
  view.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)
  view.setGeometry(400, 50, 850, 692)
  view.resizeRowsToContents()

  conn = mariadb.connect(
      user="root", password="", host="localhost", port=3306, database="IRIS"
  )

  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute("SELECT * FROM iris_table")

  allSQLRows = cur.fetchall()
  view.setRowCount(len(allSQLRows))

  for i, row_data in enumerate(allSQLRows):
      for j, data in enumerate(row_data):
          item = QTableWidgetItem()
          item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, data)
          view.setItem(i, j, item)
  ```